# ASP.NET Core 2 Razor Pages/Entity Framework - Set required field on post

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I am new to Razor Pages, and am trying to understand how I can set a required field in a page's `OnPostAsync` method. Specifically, I have a bound object which needs to include the current user's ID (from ASP.NET Identity). I can set this value in `OnPostAsync`, but the ModelState still shows as invalid. Checking the returned errors, it seems that it is not taking the updated value into consideration

Here's my current `OnPostAsync` method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    Upload.Created = DateTime.Now;
    Upload.UploaderID = _userManager.GetUserId(User);

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    _context.Uploads.Add(Upload);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
```

And here's a snippet from the `Upload` model:

```
public class Upload
{
    ...

    [Required]
    public String UploaderID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UploaderID")]
    public ApplicationUser Uploader { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Apologies if there is something obvious I am missing here, as I say I am new to Razor Pages/Entity Framework and my Google-fu has failed me.

Comment: Show us your razor content.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding the following line after setting the `UploaderID` but before the `ModelState` check:

```
ModelState.Remove("Upload.UploaderID");
```

This stops the `UploaderID` from being checked for errors with the rest of the `ModelState`.